# Is it possible to npm install only dist folder?

Tags: npm

In my first project I tried to do the above by editing .npmignore that way:

```
# compiled output
/tmp
/src
/node_modules
package.json


# dependencies
```

and then in my second project I run:

`npm install .../firstProject`

but node modules and src where installed.

Comment: You don't need the slash before the directory names. Try removing those and installing again.

Answer (score 0):

only if your dist folder has a package.json

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`npm --prefix /path/to/project install`